# ElectronJS cache

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, service-worker

I'm building an offline app using Electron JS and react JS.
of the launch steps, the first is to load a huge file (more than 1 GB and it cannot be split)
so I have to wait around 50-60 seconds until this file is fully loaded.
Is there a way to load it on the first launch and then save it to cache, so that the next time I start my app it won't take that much time?

Comment: What do you mean by load? You mean download from remote server to local machine or load from hard disk to memory?

Comment: @hackape it a local file (JSON file ). Since this file is very large, it cannot be read with fs read file or other packages. so  I had to read it via fs readstream and this process took a lot of time. this what I mean by  " load it"

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cache data in memory until the next app launch. When the app is closed, the data is gone.
There's not many ways to solve it:

#### Method 1 (cache data until the app is closed):

Read the file asynchronously (so it doesn't freeze the app) once on launch and cache it in memory by storing the data in a variable. The app will take >1GB of RAM and the cache will disappear when the app is closed.

#### Method 2 (read data in chunks):

Do you need to work on the whole dataset at once? If not, do not read the whole file, separate it into multiple chunks (files) and read specific files when you need them during the runtime.

#### Method 3 (compute while reading):

You you only need the data to calculate something once, read the json from the drive with a stream and perform computations in real time on every JSON object, during the stream. By the end of the stream all the needed computations will be done and the app will not need ~1 GB of RAM. There's a few modules for this: [stream-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-json), [bfj](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bfj), [big-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-json)

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don’t need the entire file in the first place. Can you share the nature of this big file to help better understand the problem?

"Cache" in memory is not possible, memory will be wipe out when the app quits. That’s just how memory works.

But the thing is, reading 1GB into memory shouldn’t take 60s, that’s way too long. I guess there’s other bottlenecks you need to find out.

My suggestion is try read the file synchronously, and measure the actual time it takes. You can use `"perf_hooks"` builtin module of Node.js to measure time. My guess, it’s around 1s at max just loading the file into memory, so 59s is spent doing some other stuff. The problem is very likely elsewhere.

Now if the bottleneck really is loading file from disk into memory, then `mmap` syscall might be what you need. That’s another topic though.